# Recorrer html luego de una petición GET

Tags: javascript, html, nodejs, reactjs

Estoy tratando de crear una aplicacion, la cual depende de una serie de datos que se obtienen a través de una petición hecha a la siguiente pagina:

https://eosweb.larc.nasa.gov/sse/RETScreen/

Inspeccionando la pagina, en encontré con un formulario el cual tiene el siguiente método y acción

`<form method="get" action="/cgi-bin/sse/retscreen.cgi"></form>`

Cuando en la pagina ingreso la **Latitud** y **Longitud** para obtener una serie de datos, pero al hacer la petición, me encontré con el problema de que el retorno de la información no son datos, si no una pagina web completa con dicha información.

#### Ingreso de datos

[image: imagen 1]

#### resultado

[image: imagen 2]

De la imagen anterior, la informacion que quiero obtener exactamente es

**Daily solar radiation - horizontal**

El enlace el cual retorna al momento de obtener los datos es el siguiente:

https://eosweb.larc.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/sse/retscreen.cgi?email=rets%40nrcan.gc.ca&step=1&lat=11.3734593&lon=-72.2532195&submit=Submit

Los lenguajes con los cuales estoy trabajando es React js, Javascript y Node Js.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta? ¿A qué se deben [tag:nodejs] y [tag:reactjs]? No se mencionan en el cuerpo de la pregunta salvo que estas trabajando con ellos ¿Qué es lo que has buscado/investigado?

Comment: Que mas ruben, lo pude lograr  través de esta API https://power.larc.nasa.gov/docs/v1/, creada por ellos mismos, ya pude obtener las cosas de manera clara y como `JSON`

Comment: Que bien que lo pudiste lograr. ¿Has pensado qué vas a hacer con tu pregunta?

Comment: Voy a responder mi pregunta, colocare como se obtienen ahora los resultados, le parece master?